# DisplayPort Daisy Chain on Dell Monitor not working

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, displayport, daisychaining

We have a problem where a user has 4 monitors hooked up to their Windows 10 system with an RTX 2070 for graphics.  They wanted to reserve the HDMI slot on the card, so I suggested running their 24" Dell monitors by daisy chaining the last two monitors.  We enabled DisplayPort 1.2 in the Dell settings (FYI - you need to have a valid video signal to get to the menu to turn this on) and double checked that MST was enabled for the graphics card.  After plugging in the daisy chained monitor, the monitor would flicker an image of the desktop for a second and then go black.

Windows 10 registered that the monitor was attached and daisy chained but we couldn't get an image to display.  Looking around the web and I found a lot of articles saying Dell monitors are terrible for daisy chaining but beyond not enabling DP 1.2 and MST, nothing else was a solution to our problem.  Since there is an image that flickers when you first hook it up, it seems like it is just a driver or display issue.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of testing with settings, switching ports, and switching out cables we were able to solve the problem by using a full size DisplayPort cable as the input and a full size DisplayPort as the daisy chain cable.  (No mini cables or converters.)  Using a mini-DP cable in the chain broke the ability to daisy chain, even though it is labeled as mDP-IN and the Dell manual and website don't mention this as a requirement, everything is working great now.